# Add minutes + second from separate column in Postgress

Tags: postgresql

I have a data in a table shown in ex,

And I want to add 'tot' column. I can do using replacing the : to . and do the summation but its not the proper way to add Min and sec as per my thinking.

So 1st want to convert into time HH:MM:SS ex(123:31:300)  and again convert into MM:SS

```
EX: 
     tot         min          sec           min+sec      output
     129:50 --> 02:09:00     00:00:50 -->   02:09:50 --> 129:50
     170:97-->  02:50:00     00:01:37 -->   02:51:37 --> 171:37



select  TO_CHAR('120 minutes'::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS')  ,
            TO_CHAR('62 second'::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I want to sum(min+sec) column and convert into MM:SS format

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you want to do, but you can just add them:

```
select '129:50'::interval + '02:09:00'::interval + '00:00:50'::interval
```

The result will be an interval again. You can format the output using `to_char()` to the format you want.